# Right way to Handle Rabbitmq fails with masstransit using durable queue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I use rabbitmq along with masstransit to exchange messages using the request/response mechanism every thing is working well .
one application is using durable queue and the other is using temporary queue .but when rabbitmq disk alarm is created the rabbitmq is labeled as unhealthy and swarm restart it automatically then after the rabbitmq container is restarted and labeled as healthy (disk space freed) the application with the durable queue is unable to reconnect . after i used a temporary queue instead of a durable queue the porblem goes away because the application is recreating the queue each time it reconnect  but when the rabbitmq container fails or got killed all the messages goes away . and the applications got blocked waiting for response .

**Question :**

how i can  make sure that the application reconnect each time rabbitmq fails and keep the data presistent and got reconsumed once rabbitmq is healthy again .
here my masstransit configuration for the durable queue.

```
  services.AddHealthChecks();
        //---> config Masstransit to consume messages 
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<RequestsConsumer>(con=> {
                con.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Intervals(500, 1500, 2000, 2500)); 
               }).Endpoint(e=> 
                   {
                       e.PrefetchCount = 32;
                   }
                           );

            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
            {
                config.Host(new Uri(Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMqConfig:RabbitMqAdress").Value), h =>
                {
                    Action<IRabbitMqHostConfigurator> configure = h =>
                    {
                        h.Heartbeat(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
                    };

                    h.Username(Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMqConfig:RabbitMqUser").Value);
                    h.Password(Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMqConfig:RabbitMqSecret").Value);
                  
                });
                
              
                config.ConfigureEndpoints(context,new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter("prefix-queue-name",false));
            });
            

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The loss of data in the container is due to the fact that you aren't mapping a persistent volume in either Kubernetes or Docker. If you're storing queue data in the container itself, when that container is recycled, all queue data will be lost.

I'd suggest looking at how to configure persistent volumes for the RabbitMQ database and queue storage so that recycling a container doesn't lose queue data.

> Oh, and this doesn't have anything to do with MassTransit.

Comment: even if the queue is marked as temporary ? thought the data of a temporary queue is being stored in memory and not on the disk so even if i map some volume nothing will remain , and the main quetion is how to make my app reconnect when rabbitmq restarted . thanks @chris

Comment: MassTransit will recreate any queues/exchanges when reconnecting to the broker, regardless of how it was restarted. Also, make sure you are on the current version of MassTransit. Without any logs, errors, etc. there is nothing further that can be answered on this question.

Comment: i am making the mnesia directory to be stored on the host and not in container so the messages are presistent but now after i restart rabbitmq the publisher queue is marked as skipped with all the message  and recreate new queue with the same name , where the skipped queue and its messages goes ?  thanks

Comment: mnesia is not enough, there are other folders for messages with RabbitMQ.